# How to calculate base 2 logarithm of a number in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

There are log10 and ln function in manual, but can not find how to compute log2 anymore ..

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Math_functions.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The log in any base can be calculated by division.  For this particular case:

```
select ln(x) / ln(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Per math classes in high school:

```
log2(n) ::= log10(n) / log10(2)
```

any base will do. You can do it with base **e** too, as in:

```
log2(n) ::= ln(n) / ln(2)
```